# Arrange element with transition after their container has been resized

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-transitions, css-animations

I have one resizable container with some box divs inside.

I want that every time I resize the div, the boxes inside it will adapt their position with an animation instead of suddenly appearing in the first row if you create enough space.

```
<div class="resize">
    <div class="box">
       box
    </div>
    <div class="box">
       box
    </div>
    <div class="box">
       box
    </div>
    <div class="box">
       box
    </div>
    <div class="box">
       box
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      box
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      box
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      box
    </div>
    <div class="box">
     box
    </div>
 </div>

div.resize { 
    width: 400px; 
    height: 200px; 
    border: 1px solid; 
    resize: both; 
    overflow: auto; 
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
 }

 div.box {
    width: 40px;
    height:40px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 4px;
 }
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtf37ehL/3/)

Any suggestion will be appreciated

EDIT: I can't use any libraries so things like isotope or masonry are out of the game.

Comment: The linked dupe use no library and also deal with unequally sized elements. CSS can't do this alone, as in your sample, as the left/top value needs to be set to fire the animation/transition, and when children wraps in their parent, it doesn't.